# Migrate spring boot 2.1.3 -> 2.1.4 cause problem with data jpa tests

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

After migrating from 2.1.3 to 2.1.4 or later I found that almost all DataJPA test start to fail. I found the problem that Spring Data JPA for some reasons try to put selected result to `HashSet`(cache?). `HashSet` itself calls `hashCode` and here I get a problems with Lazy loading.

Does anybody aware of what has been changed between this two releases and is it possible to turn off  or controll such behaviour?

I found [this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/16512) with migrating of String Boot, but downgrading of H2 doesn't help me

**UPDATE 1**: I use Lombok to generate `equals`&`hashCode` with all fields

Comment: Not directly related to the problem, but `Lombok`'s default implementations of `equals` and `hashCode` could be quite expensive in the case of entities and I would highly recommend you to tweak those and [exclude](https://projectlombok.org/features/EqualsAndHashCode) any mapped fields and collections if possible. Here's a good article on the topic: [How to implement equals and hashCode using the JPA entity identifier (Primary Key)](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-implement-equals-and-hashcode-using-the-jpa-entity-identifier/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case problem was with custom repository methods that return `Collection<Entity>`. After migration all this methods starts to invoke Entity's `hashCode` method which triggers lazy loading.

So the fast solution will be to change all return types from `Collection` to `List`

Also I have reported a bug https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-1729